# How to manage push notifications for multiple iOS apps on single Parse app?

Tags: ios, parsing, parse-platform

My current setup is that I have multiple iOS apps that rely on a single Parse app. I want to be able to send push notifications to individual apps via the JavaScript SDK. I have the SSL certificates required for each of the apps.

How would I go about achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you posted this question in the Parse support forum? That seems the best place to ask product-specific support questions like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, their forums seems kinda dead, and no one replied over there.

Comment: It looks like they've migrated all product support to SO and Google groups... Good luck!

Comment: I posted on the Parse google group, and they said that you just have add the additional SSL certificates onto Parse.com and their system automatically select the correct one.